# How can I get WAMP and a domain name to work on a non-standard port?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have read countless articles on setting up a domain on WAMP to listen on a port other than 80; none of them are working.

I've got Windows Server 2008 (Standard) with IIS 7 installed and running on port 80 (and 443).

I've got WAMP installed with the following configuration.

```
Listen 81
ServerName sub.example.com:81
DocumentRoot "C:/Path/To/www"
<Directory "C:/Path/To/www">

    Options All MultiViews

    AllowOverride All

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

`localhost:81 works` with the above configuration but `sub.example.com:81` does not.

Just to make sure my firewall wasn't getting in the way I have disabled it completely.

**My `sub.example.com` domain is already pointing to my server and works on IIS on port 80.**

**Also, if I disable IIS and change the Apache port from `81` to `80` it works.**

Yes, I am restarting Apache after each httpd.conf change. :-)

I don't need any other domain (or sub domains [I don't even care about localhost]) configured which is why I'm not using a VirtualHost.

Any ideas what is going on here? What could I be doing wrong?

---

**Update**

Changing `Listen` to `80` but keeping `ServerName` as `sub.example.com:81` causes navigation to `sub.example.com:80` to work; this just doesn't seem right to me. Could `ServerName` be ignoring the :port part somehow?

---

`netstat -a -n | find "TCP"`:

```
>netstat -a -n | find "TCP"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:81             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:912            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  ...
  TCP    127.0.0.1:81           127.0.0.1:49709        TIME_WAIT
  ...
```

Comment: -- comment removed since the question the comment answered was removed --

Comment: Post the output of `netstat -a -n | find "TCP"`, or at least the entry for Apache.  Specifically has Apache bound to 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, or one of the IP addresses assigned to your host?

Comment: I've updated the question to provide the full `netstat -a -n | find "TCP"` command you requested.

Comment: Updated with more info

Comment: Strange, the port on the ServerName is optional I think, try without it.

Comment: @faker. My router was the issue. oops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#facepalm

The *router* was configured to allow ports 80 and 443 only. That is why port 81 worked with localhost but not the domain.

I just needed to forward ports 80 AND 81 to the web-server and it worked.

Comment: Remember to come back and click the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

had to set up the same thing recently. There is a registry hack you have to perform to get it to work. Check out this website article for more info. Specifically the section on editing the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\ListenOnlyList.

http://beyondweblogs.com/setting-both-wamp-iis-on-80-port-no-need-of-81-now/